# Sharing class methods inbetween .NET languages

Tags: c#, java, c++, .net, j#

Me and two friends of mine are working on a programming project together but still separately, I want to add that we are all very new to programming. Now we are all going to write the same application but in different language because we are all self-taught in different languages. I will be writing the application in C#, friend 1 will be writing it in C++/CLI and friend 3 will be writing it in Java (or J#).

Now the application we are going to make is going to be a "card game engine". It will be an application that will be able to load and play different types of the standard western 52-card deck games such as Poker or Blackjack etc. This actual application we will be writing separately but what we want to load the actual "card games" as external modules, I'm guessing we'd make separate assemblies for this? Now one of our requirements here is that these "card game" modules should be able cross-language, what I mean by that is that I should be able to for example use my "BlackJack C# Module" and load it in to his "C++ version" of the game engine and vice versa.

So I have a two questions

1. Is this even possible to do? From what I understand all .NET languages can compile under the same solution? If we write the "modules" as assemblies then they should be able to access some of methods and vice versa or am I wrong here?
2. Since friend 2 isn't actually programming in a .NET language, is there an easy way to make a Java solution that will work with this? Could he perhaps write the "card game" modules as DLLs that we can then import into our separate projects? Or would it just be easier for him to write the application in J#?

Comment: Look at the can of worms that we've opened. Yikes!

Comment: J#? What? (and also Why?) Isn't it already long dead?

Answer (score 4):

> I want to add that we are all very new to programming. Now we are all going to write the same application but in different language because we are all self-taught in different languages.

The answer to this statement is easy: don't. Don't even consider doing this. Choose a single language and stick with it.

> So I have a two questions 1) Is this even possible to do? From what I understand all .NET languages can compile under the same solution? If we write the "modules" as assemblies then they should be able to access some of methods and vice versa or am I wrong here?

You can use interlanguage communication tools, but this will requiring learning some pretty advanced stuff.

> 2) Since friend 2 isn't actually programming in a .NET language, is there an easy way to make a Java solution that will work with this? Could he perhaps write the "card game" modules as DLLs that we can then import into our seperate projects? Or would it just be easier for him to write the application in J#?

Again, don't. You're making things much harder than they should be. You can't use JNI or JNA with NET wikis and easily mesh them with Java. Since you are all new to programming, again you will be much better off choosing common standards and sticking with them. Even if you weren't new to programming, you'd be better off with this.

Note that I have done some inter-language programs, but not by choice, only because I've had to. These have been simple affairs with information is passed as text using standard input and output (sockets). I've also used JNA to create Java programs that can call programs created in C, however again this has been full of many tricks and traps, several that I've fallen into, and again do not recommend this route if can be avoided. Also, and again, you cannot have Java communicate with .NET languages in this manner.

Other options for higher level inter-process communications include using a [Remote Procedure Call Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), of which there are many, but which will also add additional unneeded complexity to your program.

Comment: This should just be a comment, as it is not attempting to answer the question.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not trolling for points and have made this a community wiki, meaning up-votes and down-votes won't go to me, and also making it easier for others to contribute and edit. So please edit and improve it if you will.

Comment: CW isn't there to provide comments as answers.  That's what comments are there for.  CW is there for answers that are designed to be a composition of information from many different sources, to which this isn't, nor is there any indication that it should be.  It is your personal opinion, not an aggregation of several people's knowledge.  It should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Servy: really the question is asking for opinion and should be closed regardless.

Comment: Then vote to close it as opinion based, rather than providing a highly opinionated answer.

Comment: Well we are new to programming but not complete newbies, we're not on the level that we can't write a "FizzBizz" program. We know the basics, arrays, value types, reference types, loops, polymorphism, inheritance, etc.

Comment: @Servy are you reading his answer backward? It's not highly opinionated at all. Interlanguage IS for advanced developers and he provided the poster with a solution which is to stick to a single language

Comment: @Servy - while question can be considered of-topic I don't see this answer as "highly opinionated". Interpersonal collaboration and multy-language projects are very hard problems even for experienced developers/teams so trying to attack 3 hard problem (including learning new stuff) at a time does not sound like a good idea. (I'd say it is similar to "how to store plain text password in DB" - clearly "don't" is opinion, but it is considered common sense and not voted down for that).

Comment: @snaplemouton How is, "the actual answer would be too hard for you, so just don't bother" an answer to the question?  It's explicitly *not* answering the question.  That's fine, *as a comment*.  As a comment I'd agree with it, because it probably is too complicated for these users, but that doesn't make it an answer to the question.  Imagine some developer coming across this question through Google looking to interop between these languages, not being a beginner at all, and seeing only an answer that says, "this is to hard, don't bother".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The author of this answer is the one who said it was opinion based.  I don't think the question is opinion based, personally, I simply said that if he feels it is too opinion based to answer he should vote to close it, rather than answering a question he feels should be closed.  Personally I feel the question is probably "too broad", if anything.

Comment: @Servy It is an answer because he clearly answered the question which was: Is this even possible to do? The answer was yes. The poster stated they were new to programming so the answer was according to the question. What if a beginner search this on a search engine and find this post? He'll be informed that it isn't meant to be done by a beginner in the first place. Answering is meant to answer the poster question, not other people.

Comment: @snaplemouton I consider an answer that just says, "yes it's possible" to be a very low quality answer.  To actually be helpful it should contain quite a bit more information than that.  And I specifically asked about a non-beginner finding the question, someone to which the answer "it'll be too hard for you" would be just wrong.  If the solution is beyond the capability of this user then informing them of that is an appropriate comment; an appropriate answer is to answer the actual question asked for the sake of those to which it *isn't* too hard.

Comment: @Servy Feel free to flag the answer if you consider it innapropriate.

Comment: @Servy: regarding, `"an appropriate answer is to answer the actual question asked for the sake of those to which it isn't too hard"` -- I agree 100%. Again, this is a community wiki, so please feel free to improve on this answer for the benefit of all of us, me especially. Or provide your own independent answer that can be up-voted by all (including me if I learn from it), and can be accepted by the original poster.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If someone else wants to post an *actual* answer to the question why should they edit their actual answer into your non-answer?  If they have an actual answer they can post it as their own answer.

Comment: @Servy: I've edited my comment above prior to your comment which addresses this. So again, please provide your answer, as that's probably a better use of your and my energies at the moment than this discussion which is going no where and will likely be kaboshed by a moderator soon.

Comment: I use C++/CLI and VB .NET in a single project.  It works just fine.

Comment: @NathanM: try throwing Java in the mix as the OP is suggesting. Then come back and let us know how fine it is working.

Comment: I thought he said J#?

Comment: @NathanM: J# doesn't even exist any more.

Comment: Okay, I understand, now.  And, I was aware it wasn't in VS 2013, but they could have been using an older version.